# What is the best way to check correspondence in r

Tags: string, r

I am trying to check if two variables have a one to one relation. One of the two variables contains characters of address, while the other contain a ID to the address. I would like to see if it's a one to one correspondence.
I was thinking about converting characters to ASCII code or assign them a value using a math function. But I want to know if there's other easier and more effective ways to do so.

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* sample of your data? It is unclear what you mean at the moment. See [creating a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here:  http://bit.ly/SORepro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `table`, and check if the resulting matrix has exactly one 1 
in each row and in each column. That also tells you where the duplicates are.

```
d <- data.frame( 
  x = sample( LETTERS, 10, replace=TRUE ),
  y = sample( LETTERS, 10, replace=TRUE )
)
m <- table(d) != 0
all( rowSums( m ) == 1 ) && all( colSums( m ) == 1 )
```

But if there is a lot of data, this is not very efficient.
You can use a sparse matrix instead.

```
library(Matrix)
m <- sparseMatrix(
  i = as.numeric( as.factor( d$x ) ),
  j = as.numeric( as.factor( d$y ) ),
  x = rep( 1, nrow(d) )
)
m <- m > 0
all( rowSums( m ) == 1 ) && all( colSums( m ) == 1 )
```

You can also use `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf( "SELECT x, COUNT( DISTINCT y ) AS n FROM d GROUP BY x HAVING n > 1" )
sqldf( "SELECT y, COUNT( DISTINCT x ) AS n FROM d GROUP BY y HAVING n > 1" )
```

You can also simply count how many different pairs you have:
it should be the same as the number of distinct values of `x`
and of `y`.

```
nrow( unique(d) ) == length(unique(d$x)) && nrow( unique(d) ) == length(unique(d$y))
```